# Anonymous function is not working in script file

Tags: javascript, jquery, anonymous-function

I have created a tab-menu for my website. Following JavaScript function works well when I run them on localhost -

```
(function ($) {
    var tab = $(".xmenu > .xmenu-nav > li > a"),
        content = $(".xmenu > .xmenu-content > div");
    tab.click(function (e) {
        content.removeClass("active");
        tab.removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
        $($(this).attr("href")).addClass("active");
        e.preventDefault();
    });
})(jQuery)
```

But when I use them on my site they does not work. The file that contains above anonymous function (xmenu.js) is loaded correctly after jQuery 1.10. You can check it [here](http://www.travelance.ca/products/trips-demo/). When I click on multi-trip it does not work as expected, but when I run above function in console it started working well.

Does someone knows why above function does not run when the file (xmenu.js) is loaded, but works well when I copy and paste it from the file to console and hit enter.

### Thank you in advance!

Also check this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jDdbj/), its working well here.

Comment: Check my answer, that fixes the problem for you. The reason why jsfiddle works is because by defult, jsfiddle runs the code onLoad. The onLoad event is fired after the onDOMReady event, so that's why it works in jsfiddle. Outside jsfiddle you're going to have to make it run after DOM ready though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should load the function on DOM ready. This can be done via [jQuery's `.ready()`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/), or its shorthand syntax, which I applied to the provided code:

```
    jQuery(function($) {
        var tab = $(".xmenu > .xmenu-nav > li > a"),
            content = $(".xmenu > .xmenu-content > div");
        tab.click(function (e) {
            content.removeClass("active");
            tab.removeClass("active");
            $(this).addClass("active");
            $($(this).attr("href")).addClass("active");
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });
```

This should load the tab switching script after your page has "initialised": after the DOM is ready to be used, which is exactly what you're using when you do something like `$(".xmenu > .xmenu-nav > li > a")`.

Comment: You combine the IIFE and the ready statement: `jQuery(function($) { ... });`.

Comment: I did not even know that... <del>*It doesn't mention that on the jquery docs, does it? I went over it quicky, and couldn't find anything about it. Weird...*</del> nevermind, it's explained just after the Example header on the page

Comment: @FelixKling I've modified my post. Thanks for the tip, I think that is going to be useful to me too some time.